# Unity3D dragging object on sphere

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry, draggable

I'm working on getting my object dragging to work properly on a sphere, and i was hoping i could get a little help here.

I would like an accurate placement of the object according to the mouse position. It's a little difficult to explain, but here's a video showing how it is currently working.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQnmARZ_at4&feature=youtu.be

If someone point my in the right direction in fixing this, it'd be much appreciated.

Here's the script i'm using:

```
#pragma strict

var myTransform : Transform;
var target : Transform;
var beingDragged : boolean;
var distance : float;
var targetPosition : Vector3;
var distanceToTarget : Vector3;
var placementPosition : Vector3;
var t : Matrix4x4;

var gameManager : GameObject;
var buildModeScript : BuildMode;


function Start () 
{
    myTransform = transform;
    gameManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("gameManager");
    buildModeScript = gameManager.GetComponent(BuildMode);
    target = myTransform.parent;
}

function Update () 
{
    if (buildModeScript.buildMode)
    {
        if (beingDragged)
        {
            DragMe();
        }
    }
}

function DragMe ()
{
    var mouseX = -Input.mousePosition.x;
    var mouseY = Input.mousePosition.y;

    targetPosition = target.position;
    distance = (target.localScale.x / 2) + 1;

    //Calculate position on sphere
    distanceToTarget = new Vector3(0, 0, -distance);
    t = Matrix4x4.TRS(targetPosition, Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, 0), Vector3.one);
    placementPosition = t.MultiplyPoint(distanceToTarget);

    //Put me there
    myTransform.position = placementPosition;
    myTransform.LookAt(target);
}

function OnMouseDown ()
{
    beingDragged = true;
}

function OnMouseUp ()
{
    beingDragged = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have unity in front of me to get you a complete working example, but see if this gets you in the right direction. If you have a collider on your sphere you can just use a [raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)

```
var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition); 
var hit : RaycastHit;
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 100))
{
     // TODO: use info from hit.point
}
```

If you don't want to use a raycast, you could get the world position and calculate the closest point. To get the world position see [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i've worked a little on it, and i made it work perfectly for what i need. Thank you very much :) Here's a video showing the end result if you're interested in that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mt-McSajXgw&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

To those looking for something similar here's my new script:

```
#pragma strict

var myTransform : Transform;
var target : Transform;
var beingDragged : boolean;

var gameManager : GameObject;
var buildModeScript : BuildMode;


function Start () 
{
    myTransform = transform;
    gameManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("gameManager");
    buildModeScript = gameManager.GetComponent(BuildMode);
    target = myTransform.parent;
}

function Update () 
{
    if (beingDragged)
    {
        DragMe();
    }
}

function DragMe ()
{
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition); 
    var hit : RaycastHit;

    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 1000))
    {
        if (hit.transform == target)
        {
            myTransform.position = hit.point;
            myTransform.LookAt(target);
        }
    }
}

function OnMouseDown ()
{
    if (buildModeScript.buildMode)
    {
        if (beingDragged == true)
        {
            beingDragged = false;
        }
        else if (beingDragged == false)
        {
            beingDragged = true;
        }
    }
}
```